# Is it possible to set a specific file path in phone gap?

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, cordova

I'm currently working on finding out what PhoneGap can/can't do in iPhone app development. So far I have managed to write a file to the LocalFileSystem using FileWriter and on the click of a button reads the file back to the user. I have been asked to find a way to set the app so when the app writes a file, the file is saved to a folder/location specified by the user. I've been looking, but I can't find any information to do with this. Is it even possible to do so? And if so, can you please help me?

(*I am using JavaScript, HTML and PhoneGap in Xcode for this app*)

Here's the code I used to write/read the file using the LocalFileSystem;

```
    var reader;
    var text;
    var myFileSystem;

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function myfile() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotmyFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        myFileSystem = fileSystem;
        console.log(fileSystem.name);
    }

    function gotmyFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme2.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
            console.log(file);
            text = evt.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function readmyfile() {
        var myPara = document.getElementById("mytext");
        myPara.innerText = text;
    }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
```

This all works, but is there something i should add/remove to make it work?

Thanks a lot in advance xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS apps are sandboxed and you can write only to specific directories. more details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).